# CoordinatorLayout. Скролл экрана останавливается, если тянуть за AppBar

Tags: android, coordinator-layout, collapsing-toolbar-layout

В приложении используется `CoordinatorLayout` c `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Внутри, под ним `RecyclerView` со `ScrollingViewBehavior`. Всё работает корректно (`AppBar` схлопывается по скроллу), но мне хотелось бы убрать следующее поведение:

Если я свайпаю не `RecyclerView`, а область `AppBar` (снизу вверх) — то экран скроллится только до тех пор, пока не схлопнется `AppBar`. Для дальнейшего скролла надо свайпить снова.

Дело в том, что размер `AppBar` достаточно большой — почти 90% от высоты экрана, и по нему сложно не попасть.  А такое поведение воспринимается однозначно как баг.

Пытался играться со скролл-флагами, но не добился нужного поведения (да и подозреваю, что это не то, что нужно). Никто не лечил? Это как то можно победить?

```
swipeRefreshTopLayout {
    setProgressViewOffset(false, 0, actionBarHeight)
    setOnRefreshListener { vm.updateProduct() }
    setRefreshing(vm.loading)

    frameLayout {

        coordinatorLayout {
            topPadding = statusBarHeight

            appBarLayout {

                backgroundColorResource = R.color.white_100
                showShadowOnCollapsed(vm.percentScrolled)
                onOffsetChange(vm.percentScrolled) {
                    with(it) { verticalOffset.toFloat().absoluteValue / appBarLayout?.totalScrollRange.safe().toFloat() }
                }

                collapsingToolbarLayout {

                    frameLayout {

                        viewPager = viewPager {
                            tag = tag()
                            offscreenPageLimit = 5
                            clipToPadding = false
                            transitionNameCompat = pagerTransitionName(vm.product.get()?.serverId.safe())
                            pageMargin = dip(12)
                            setPaddings(left = screenWideSideSpacing(), right = screenWideSideSpacing())
                            setItems(vm.gallery.mapSelf { items }, vm.galleryBindings)
                            setCurrentPage(GalleryActivity.selectedItem.toFlowableLatest())
                        }.lparams(matchParent, screenHeight - productShortContainerHeight * 3 / 2)

                    }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent) {
                        collapseMode = COLLAPSE_MODE_PARALLAX
                    }

                    toolbar = toolbar {

                        setAlpha(vm.percentScrolled.onlyPresent())
                        navigationIconResource = R.drawable.zzz_arrow_left
                        backgroundColorResource = R.color.white_100
                        setNavigationOnClickListener {
                            router<MainRouter>()?.goBack()
                        }
                        verticalLayout {
                            boldText {
                                textSizeDimen = largeTextSizeResource
                                setText(vm.product.onlyPresent().map { it.brand.safe() })
                            }
                            linearLayout {
                                boldText {
                                    gone(vm.product.onlyPresent().map { !it.isDiscount })
                                    textColorResource = R.color.hint_color
                                    setTextStrikeThru()
                                    setText(vm.product.onlyPresent().map { ruble(it.price) })
                                }.lparams(wrapContent, wrapContent) {
                                    rightMargin = dip(12)
                                }
                                boldText {
                                    setText(vm.product.onlyPresent().map { ruble(it.priceWithDiscount) })
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }.lparams(matchParent, actionBarHeight) {
                        collapseMode = COLLAPSE_MODE_PIN
                    }


                }.lparams(width = matchParent) {
                    scrollFlags = SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL or SCROLL_FLAG_EXIT_UNTIL_COLLAPSED
                }

                tabLayout {
                    setAlpha(vm.percentScrolled.onlyPresent().map { percent ->
                        if (percent < TAB_ALPHA_THRESHOLD) 1f else 1f - (percent - TAB_ALPHA_THRESHOLD) / (1f - TAB_ALPHA_THRESHOLD)
                    }.doOnNext { Timber.d("$it") })
                    backgroundResource = R.drawable.center_horizontal_line
                    tabRippleColorResource = R.color.transparent
                    tabGravity = TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL
                    tabMode = TabLayout.MODE_FIXED
                    hide()
                    hide(vm.gallery.mapSelf { items.size <= 1 })
                    setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(color(R.color.colorAccent))
                    setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(dip(2))
                    setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
                }.lparams(matchParent, dip(3)) {
                    leftMargin = screenWideSideSpacing()
                    rightMargin = screenWideSideSpacing()
                }

            }.lparams(width = matchParent)

            recyclerView {
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                setItems(vm.items, vm.binding)
                addOnScrollListener(HidingScrollListener(0, object : HidingScrollListener.ObserverAdapter() {
                    override fun onRecyclerScrollsDown() {
                        (activity as? MainActivity)?.run {
                            showFab()
                            showBottomBarAnimated()
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onRecyclerScrollsUp() {
                        (activity as? MainActivity)?.run {
                            hideFab()
                            hideBottomBarAnimated()
                        }
                    }
                }))

            }.lparams(matchParent, matchParent) {
                behavior = AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior()
            }

            imageView {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                    elevation = dip(8).toFloat()
                setRoundRippleClickAnimation()
                padding = clickableIconPadding
                imageResource = R.drawable.zzz_arrow_left_white_border
                setOnClickListener { router<MainRouter>()?.goBack() }
            }.lparams(clickableIconSize, actionBarHeight) {
                leftMargin = dip(10)
            }

            mediumText {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                    elevation = dip(8).toFloat()
                rightPadding = screenSideSpacing()
                gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
                textSizeDimen = largeTextSizeResource
                setLabel(vm.product.map { Optional.of(it?.label) })
            }.lparams(wrapContent, actionBarHeight) {
                gravity = Gravity.END
            }

            context.asAppCompatActivity()
                    .setExitSharedElementCallback(createSharedElementCallback {
                        viewPager.run {
                            (findViewWithTag(tag(currentItem)) as ViewGroup)
                                    .findView<ImageView>()
                        }
                    })
        }

        frameLayout {
            gone()
            onAdd(vm.added)
            topPadding = statusBarHeight
            backgroundColorResource = R.color.green
            boldText {
                textSizeDimen = largeTextSizeResource
                textColorResource = R.color.white_100

                textResource = R.string.added_to_wihlist
            }.lparams(wrapContent, wrapContent, Gravity.CENTER)

            imageView {
                imageResource = R.drawable.ic_arrow_forward_white
            }.lparams(iconSize, iconSize, Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL or Gravity.END) {
                rightMargin = dip(24)
            }
        }.lparams(matchParent, dip(82))
    }
}
```

Comment: разметку покажите

Comment: @AndreyMihalev добавил

Comment: я в замешательстве, сначала подумал что вы сбросили не то что нужно, а именно код класса, посмотрел на синтаксис, что это если не секрет, просто интересно так как вижу я это впервые :)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko это Anko, набор расширений для kotlin. Плюс там подмешано немного моей mvvm-библиотеки, но это отражается только в обращении к vm.

Comment: Н самом деле дело не в разметке. Вся суть вопроса в самом вопросе и не надо штудировать разметку, чтобы понять, что у меня не так. Я и так написал, что у меня не так. Надо просто включить воображение и вспомнить, сталкивались ли вы с таким или нет, а может просто  знаете, как захендлить

Comment: Если вы считаете что разметка не важна, то удачи.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev Конечно важна. Но тут не вопрос о том, что у меня не так. У меня всё так, потому что я вижу именно то, что должно происходить исходя из нормального поведения CollasingToolbar. Тут вопрос как можно захендлить вполне себе нормальное его поведение так, чтобы оно соответствовало моим ожиданиям. Разметка на месте, Ваши советы?)